# What is the first use of Arctic Breath in the DCEU?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe

In *Justice League*,

> Superman cools Steppenwolf's axe with his Arctic Breath which allows Wonder Woman to destroy it with her sword.

Is this the first use of Arctic Breath by a Kryptonian in the DCEU?

Comment: Your title asks for the first use, the question specifies Kryptonian?

Comment: @JohnP, usually title questions are a little more streamlined to provide a hook, and to not be too unwieldy, and then the text provides context and the more detailed question.     Do you have an example of this power from a non-Kryptonian?

Comment: I've removed `superman` and `justice-league-2017` as the scope was not limited to superman or to Justice League 2017, but to Kryptonians and the entire DCEU, but if you disagree I guess you can roll back.

Comment: I've thought about this for a while, the question is definitely about superman, I've added the tag back in.

Answer (score 8):

### Yes, this is the first occurrence.

There have only been two films that have featured Superman prior to Justice League. Neither of which feature either Superman or any other Kryptonian using the Arctic Breath power (if you're willing to accept the wiki as a source, it's covered [here](http://dccomicsextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Breath), otherwise I've seen both films and it does not occur).

As an aside, the last time it was used by Superman (on-screen) was in 2011, on the TV series Smallville. [The episode](http://smallville.wikia.com/wiki/Arctic_breath?file=918Smallville0839.jpg) aired in May 2011. It has, however, been used by a Kryptonian more recently; notably by Supergirl from the CW's Arrowverse.

[image]

Comment: Maybe in the DCEU, but in Superman the Movie (1978) Superman uses his super breath to cool down a gasoline tanker in his battle with General Zod.

Comment: @dean1957 well the question was set in the scope of the DCEU, I then decided to add in the most recent use for both cases, adding the first use in general could be an interesting point too.